# Get all customers whose total spendings are $1000 or more

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to retrieve the customers (ID and name) who have spent at least $1000.

The tables concerned have the following simplified shape :

- Sales : {**SaleID**, CustomerID, Amount}
- Customers : {**CustomerID**, CustomerName}

This query gives me what I want, but I think having to compute the SUM twice is a sign that I'm perhaps not approaching this problem correctly.

```
SELECT
    t2.CustomerID, t2.CustomerName, SUM(t1.Amount) AS total_spent
FROM
    Sales t1
JOIN
    Customers t2 ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
GROUP BY
    t2.CustomerID, t2.CustomerName
HAVING
    SUM(t1.Amount) >= 1000
```

Comment: I think I found a way to get around using SUM twice, but would like expert opinion on whether or not this is best practice.

Remove the HAVING clause, and wrap the query inside an outer SELECT followed by a WHERE.

Comment: This is not a bad practice as the database engine will optimise the query.

Comment: I have no issues with your query, it returns correct results unless you have duplicate identical entries in the `Customers` table. Check your data first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is not a bad approach. Another way you can do this :

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT t2.CustomerID, t2.CustomerName, 
     SUM(t1.Amount) AS total_spent FROM Sales t1
     JOIN Customers t2 ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
     GROUP BY t2.CustomerID, t2.CustomerName 
    ) AS Result
WHERE total_spent >= 1000
```

You can check the performance, but I think this one would be better to use.

Comment: I think you will find both perform the same - easy to test.